# Create UnderLine font with PdfFileWriter to report an error

Tags: c#, winforms, font-style

```
error:font resource cannot have underline or strikeout.
PdfFileWriter.PdfFont font = PdfFileWriter.PdfFont.CreatePdfFont(pdfDocument, FontName, FontStyle.Underline);
```

I looked at the help documentation for `PdfFileWriter` and didn't find any useful help.
Do you have any good plans or suggestions?

Comment: I'm not an expert on this matter, but it sounds to me that the font you are using does nog support ubnderline and strikeout.

Comment: You often have to fake these thing; e.g. place one textblock,  graphic, or icon over another. They typically have transparent backgrounds. The Segoe MLD2 Font for example allows you to place a black ring over a red circle (font icons) to create a red icon with a black ring.